# Trouble forming Amazon Product Advertising API's CartCreate Items object in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-product-api, amazon-product-advertising-api

I'm using node-apac (https://github.com/dmcquay/node-apac) to communicate with Amazon's Product Advertising API, but I'm having trouble forming the Items object for the CartCreate operation. Amazon's just returning formatting errors no matter how I do it.

The object I'm sending to the operation looks like this:

```
'Items': {
      'Item': {
            'OfferListingId': itemId,
            'Quantity': quantity
      }
}
```

I've also tried sending the object as arrays:

```
'Items': [{
      'Item': [{
            'OfferListingId': itemId,
            'Quantity': quantity
      }]
}]
```

But it seems to dislike the structure of the object no matter how I create it. In the second example, for instance, the error returned is "Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include Item."

Any advice would be massively appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this, I managed to get it working. The keys were named wrong. It should have been:

```
var data = {
  'Item.1.ASIN': itemId,
  'Item.1.Quantity': quantity
}
```